# cuda streams: callback not getting called after stream execution

Tags: c++, cuda, callback

I am having trouble with the cuda streams callback function. The problem is that it does not execute after the kernel is run. I am encapsulating the cuda streams in a C++ class as follows:

```
class Stream
{
public:
    Stream();
    void run(float *input, int points);
    ~Stream();
    static void CUDART_CB callback(cudaStream_t stream,
                                   cudaError_t status,
                                   void * user_data);

private:
    void callback_function();

    cudaStream_t s;

};
```

Now, I have the callback function setup as suggested before as follows:

```
void CUDART_CB StreamWorkflow::callback(cudaStream_t stream,
                                    cudaError_t status,
                                    void * user_data)
{
    Stream* thiz = (Stream *)(user_data);
    thiz->callback_function();
}
```

And the constructor sets up the stream and attaches the callback

```
Stream::Stream()
{
    checkCudaErrors(cudaStreamCreate(&s));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaStreamAddCallback(s, Stream::callback, this, 0));
}
```

Now the run method calls the cuda kernel on this stream and I know this executes fine. It is implemented like:

```
void Stream::run(float *f, int p)
{
    dim3 block(16, 16);
    dim3 grid((int)ceil(double(p) / 256.0));
    my_kernel(f, p, grid, block, s);
    checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    getLastCudaError("kernel launch failed");
}
```

My problem is that the callback only gets called when the constructor gets executed. So, as soon as the object is created the callback_function() gets executed through the registered callback(). The kernel gets executed multiple times by the host and it never executes the callback function when it is finished. I can see the kernel is executed successfully but the callback never comes.

Do I have to register the callback **everytime** the kernel is run (so register this callback before executing the run function) or am I doing something really wrong here?

Comment: Without  full example, it will be very hard to provide an answer. This sounds like a scope problem, but without real code, it will be very hard to say for sure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're probably confused about how callbacks work.    In general, when you issue a CUDA operation to a CUDA stream, that CUDA operation is executed when all preceding CUDA activity issued to that stream has been completed (and before any subsequent activity issued to that stream is begun).

callbacks are no different.  If you want a call back to execute after a kernel has executed, then you must issue that callback to that stream after you issue the kernel.  The definition of the add callback function is *not*:

> "any time a kernel completes in this stream, run this callback"

The [definition of the add callback function](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__STREAM.html#group__CUDART__STREAM_1g74aa9f4b1c2f12d994bf13876a5a2498) *is*:

> "when the CUDA stream has completed all CUDA activity up to this point, then execute the callback"

or, quoting directly from the documentation:

> The function to call **once preceding stream operations are complete**

Therefore this constructor makes no sense to me:

```
Stream::Stream()
{
    checkCudaErrors(cudaStreamCreate(&s));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaStreamAddCallback(s, Stream::callback, this, 0));
}
```

This constructor says:

"create a CUDA stream"

"when all previously issued activity to this stream is complete, run this callback"

But of course, you haven't issued any activity to that stream, so the callback runs immediately, (and only once,) right after stream creation.

> "so register this callback before executing the run function"

No, if this is what you want:

> The problem is that it does not execute after the kernel is run

then move your add callback function to **after** your kernel launch, and I think you're more likely to see the activity you want.

Comment: This was really the issue. You were right, I got confused with how the callbacks worked in CUDA. I thought you register it once with the stream and it would get called everytime any kernel is executed through that stream.