# Calling Callback function from different cpp causes bad_function_call

Tags: c++, opencv, callback

I'm currently working on an OpenCV project where I want to call a callback function in main.cpp from a different cpp.
The problem I'm facing is that when I want to call the function I get a bad_function_call because the Callback function is a null.

My main.cpp looks like this:

```
 PointDetection *detect;
 detect->houghCallback = [hPublisher] (std::vector<cv::Vec4i> data) {
        //do something
 };
```

my PointDetector.hpp, which gets included by the PointDetector.cpp:

```
 std::function <void (std::vector<cv::Vec4i> data) houghCallback;
```

My PointDetector.cpp, where I call the function looks like this:

```
 void PointDetector::houghDetectCb(int status, void *userData) {
        std::vector<cv::Vec4i> houghPointsResult;
        PointDetector *self = static_cast<PointDetector *>(userData);    //This includes every variable in the hpp except the houghCallback for some reason 
        self->houghCallback(houghPointsResult);                          //This causes the bad_function_call because houghCallback is Null 
 }
```

Does somebody know if it is possible to call the Callback like this?

Comment: My guess would be, `self` is a dangling pointer referring to an object that has already been destroyed. The problem is somewhere in the code not shown. Show a [mcve]

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I found the solution see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: I was calling stream.enqueqeHostCallback before the actual GPU Operation (See this question: [cuda streams: callback not getting called after stream execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29566346/cuda-streams-callback-not-getting-called-after-stream-execution))